# A word for "that which defies the odds"

Tags: adjectives

Simply put, I'm looking for a word that would mean "That which defies the odds" or "he who defies the odds", or anything similar to that. It would have to be an adjective. Perhaps there isnt an english word for it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You want a word other than 'lucky'?

Comment: 'Survivor' carries the strong connotation (at least) of surviving when not expected to.

Comment: miraculous, perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

> **serendipity**  NOUN
>   The occurrence and development of events by chance in a happy or beneficial way.
>   [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/serendipity)

Answer (score 0):

How about -

## Unexpected

> adjective
> : not expected or regarded as likely to happen.

([From Lexico](http://english.oxforddictionaries.com/unexpected))

Answer (score 0):

Why not the obvious? “The odds-defying X”. Or “improbable “